# wrapping a list over multiple lines yaml

Tags: yaml

In YAML I know that it is possible to wrap a string over multiple lines like this:

```
my_string: this is my very very very very very reeeeeeeally quite long string
```

is equivalent to:

```
my_string:> 
       this is my very very very very
       very reeeeeeeally quite long string
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with a list? Something like:

```
[my, very, long, list, that, is, waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay, tooooo, long]
```

written as:

```
my_list:>
     [my, very, long, 
     list, that, is, 
     waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay, tooooo, long]
```

but broken up over multiple lines, the docs were not specific on this. And when I tried to do it the way above when I loaded the YAML file I got the error:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
```

Comment: Both your second and last examples are single strings scalars with embedded newlines (try pasting them into http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/). If you want to specify a mapping from `my_string` to a value, you have to include a space (or newline) after the colon. Your error message comes probably from the next line, because you can't juxtapose scalars and key/value pairs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have there is a ["Flow sequence"](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790320) and there is no requirement that it is put on a single line. You do however want to keep things indented relative to the (mapping) key it belongs to (although some parsers relax this requirement):

```
my_list: [my, very, long, 
         list, that, is, 
         waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay, tooooo, long]
```

Alternatively you can decide to use [block style sequence](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2797382), but that is less flexible as each sequence element **has** to be on its own line:

```
my_list:
- my
- very
- long
- list
- that
- is
- waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay
- tooooo
- long
```

In this case you can, but don't have to, indent the dash (`-`) before the list elements relative to the mapping key (`my_list`)

That you got the error `mapping values are not allowed here` is most likely because you did put a key-value map after the

```
my_list:>
     [my, very, long, 
     list, that, is, 
     waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay, tooooo, long]
xyz: 123
```

you get that error on the above with [online parsers](http://%20%20%20%20my_list:%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[my,%20very,%20long,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list,%20that,%20is,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay,%20tooooo,%20long]%20%20%20%20%20xyz:%20123). There reason for that is that, because there is no space after the colon, `my_list` is never key for a mapping, but the beginning of a multiline scalar (string), with embedded newlines converted to spaced, that [ends with `long]`](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=my_list%3A%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20[my%2C%20very%2C%20long%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20list%2C%20that%2C%20is%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay%2C%20tooooo%2C%20long]%0A%0A&type=canonical_yaml). It is essentially equivalent to writing:

```
"my_list:> [my, very, long, list, that, is, waaaaaaaaaaaaaaay, tooooo, long]"
```

because the space-after-colon is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out, YAML has another list syntax like this:

```
my_list:
    - this
    - is
    - my 
    - reaaaaally
    - long 
    - list
```

Which allows me to wrap a list